# how to call an inner method

Tags: python, python-3.x

in the below code i am trying to understand the differences between global and local variables. At the runtime the following error is generated:#

```
File "m:\python lessons\globalAndLocal_1.py", line 21, in globalVsLocal_1
    self.g2()
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

**Note**

```
 i want to call g2 from within g1
```

please tell me how to call method g2()

**code**:

```
class globalVsLocal_1:

    def f1(self):
        global a #this is to reference a variable declared in the global context.
        print ("f1 a = %s"%(a)) # if global a was not declared in the first line, generates this line an error as variable a not defined is
        a = a + 10            
        print ("f1 a = %s"%(a))

    def f2(self):
        print("f2 a = %s"%(a))

    def f3(self):
        print("f3 b = %s"%(b))
        #b = b + 1   #activating this line will yield an error. Because the absence of the keyword global. the print statement works immaculately without global keyword because it just reads the value without 
                        #manipulate it
        print("f3 b = %s"%(b))

    def g1(self):
        def g2():
                print("g2 b = %s "%(b))
    g2()

a = 1
b = 20
obj = globalVsLocal_1()
obj.f1()
obj.f2()
obj.f3()
obj.g1()
```

Comment: (you can't without modifying the code.) why do you have to make `g2` local? Can't you make it a method like the other methods?

Comment: `self.g2()` appear nowhere in your code

Comment: @user202729 because i am learning about global and local vars

Comment: Okay... in normal Python code, if you want to call it from outside, don't make it local.

Comment: @user202729 pls see the note posted

Comment: Ah okay. Then just **call it within g1**. white spaces are significant in Python.

Comment: And don't abuse code formatting for highlighting.

Comment: (ouch) just notice the issue mentioned above, which means that you didn't post a [example].

Comment: You could also use the closure pattern and return g2 from g1. Then you could do `g2 = obj.g1(); g2()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of g2() is local to the function g1() so you cannot call it outside.  It's also unusual that you try to call g2() in the middle of the class definition.

```
class ...
   def g1(self):
     def g2():
        print("g2 b = %s "%(b))

     g2()
```

Comment: how to modify the code so I cann call g2??

Comment: Define g2() at the same level as g1()

Comment: @LetsamrIt Don't make g2 local (i.e. make it a normal method like the other methods). You can only call g2 from within g1.

Comment: pls see the note posted

Answer (score 0):

```
class globalVsLocal_1:

    def f1(self):
        global a #this is to reference a variable declared in the global context.
        print ("f1 a = %s"%(a)) # if global a was not declared in the first line, generates this line an error as variable a not defined is
        a = a + 10            
        print ("f1 a = %s"%(a))

    def f2(self):
        print("f2 a = %s"%(a))

    def f3(self):
        print("f3 b = %s"%(b))
        #b = b + 1   #activating this line will yield an error. Because the absence of the keyword global. the print statement works immaculately without global keyword because it just reads the value without 
        #manipulate it
        print("f3 b = %s"%(b))

    def g1(self):
        def g2():
            print("g2 b = %s "%(b))
        g2()

a = 1
b = 20
obj = globalVsLocal_1()
obj.f1()
obj.f2()
obj.f3()
obj.g1()
```

You were missing indentation while called g2.
This gives the following output

```
f1 a = 1
f1 a = 11
f2 a = 11
f3 b = 20
f3 b = 20
g2 b = 20
```